# General question about proving that a function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

This is a general question about a concept so let's assume $f(x)$ is some function.

Let $f(x)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    some-function & \quad \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
    some-other-function & \quad \text{if $x=0$}
  \end{array} \right.$

I know that if I prove that $f'(x)$ exists on all of the domain of the function, then it's differentiable.
But I also know that if the function is not continuous, it can't be differentiable.
What I don't understand is, how the fact that I show that the derivative exists for every $x\in domain$, makes sure that the function is continuous?

For a more concrete example,
Let $g(x)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \frac{sinx}{x} & \quad \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if $x=0$}
  \end{array} \right.$

It's obvious that the function is differentiable at $\frac{sinx}{x}$ and at $1$, but why does it imply that the function is necessarily continuous?
Is it enough to say that since it's differentiable when $x\neq 0$ and when $x=0$ then it's differentiable?

Comment: For your first question, imagine that you have a discontinuous function $f$ (for sake of simplicity, in one variable $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$), let $a$ be a point of discontinuity. What will happen to the quotiens $\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{h}$, $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ as $h$ goes to $0$?

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández The quotients will be infinity, which implies that the derivative at $a$ doesn't exist? But If I show that the function on $x=0$ is differentiable, and also at $x\neq 0$, does it mean that the function in the point of "transition" between those points is also differentiable? (I hope it's clear what I mean).
For instance - if the function is differentiable at 0, and also at 0.0001, what makes sure it's differentiable at 0.00000001?

Comment: 0.00000001 is in the set $x\neq 0$ so you have no problems there, in the poin $x=0$ and the "transition", what is happening is that differentiability is not a pointwise concept, is a local one, that is, when you talk about the derivative at some point, it includes how the function behaves around the point, so that takes care of the "transition" aspect. When you are computing $g'(x)$ you can't just say the derivative of $1$ is $0$ so $g'(0)=0$ imagine changing $1$ for $|x|+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a function is defined “by cases” has no relevance, except perhaps on *how* you decide whether it is continuous or differentiable.

The theorem “a function that's differentiable at a point $c$ is continuous at $c$” holds whatever is the definition of the function.

In your case, the derivative at $0$ is, if it exists,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x}\mathrel{\color{red}{=}}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^2}=0
$$
where the “how you decide” mentioned above comes into place: since we're computing the limit for $x\to0$, the value of $f(x)$ when we perform the step denoted with the red equal sign can be taken as $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Thus the function $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and, by general theorem, continuous at $0$.

Of course, the continuity at zero can be checked separately, but it's not necessary as we proved differentiability directly.

Comment: Why do I have to use the definition of the derivative, and not just calculate the derivative of $1$, and the derivative of $\frac{sinx}{x}$ separately? (Which are $0$ and $\frac{xcosx-sinx}{x^2}$)

Comment: @Lilo: consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x=0\\ 1&x=1\\2&x=2\\ \pi&x=\pi\\ \dots&\end{cases}\\=\begin{cases}a&\textrm{if }x=a~\textrm{for all}~a\end{cases}\\=x$. Would you agree that its derivative is not everywhere $0$, even though we can define it pointwise?

Comment: Because the derivative at x=0 doesn't only depend on the value f(0), but also on the values f(x) when x is very close to 0.

Comment: Thanks, I got this point.
But what I still don't understand, is why it is enough to show that the derivative exists at $x_0=0$, without checking the case that $x_0\neq 0$

Comment: @Lilo For $x\ne0$, the quotient rule applies.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0).$$
Which is really the same as
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))=0.$$
Now you probably recognize the expression on the left side. It appears in the difference quotient:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}.$$
A function is differentiable at $x_0$ if the limit of this quotient as $x\to x_0$ exists. The denominator is guaranteed to converge to $0$. But for the limit of the quotient to exist, the numerator then also has to go to $0$, otherwise the whole thing diverges. And we just noticed before that the numerator going to $0$ is exactly what's needed for continuity.

Note that none of this has anything to do with how the function has been written down, wether it's piecewise or not, doesn't matter ($\sqrt{x^2}$ and $\vert x\vert$ have the exact same properties, since they are equal, but $\vert x\vert$ is defined piecewise, and $\sqrt{x^2}$ isn't). How we represent a function can at most influence how convenient our calculations end up being. But the fact that differentiability implies continuity isn't based on such a representation.